# How to clone a row on button click in essential js 1.X ejgrid widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, syncfusion

I am attempting to clone a row in ejgrid widget within essential JS 1.X Syncfusion.

I have tried various methods from old school low level JS, jQuery, and have referred to the official JS API documentation to no avail. Hoping someone out there has used this technology before...

```
//grid population
$('#lstSelected').ejGrid({
            dataSource: [],
            enableRowHover: true,
            allowTextWrap: true,
            allowSorting: true,
            allowFiltering: false,
            allowSelection: false,
            allowResizing: true,
            allowScrolling: true,
            scrollSettings: { height: $(window).height() - 250, width: "100%" },
            columns: [
                { headerText: "", template: true, templateID: "#savechktmp", width: 50, textAlign: "center", type: "string" },
                { field: "BP_ID", visible: false, isPrimaryKey: true, defaultValue: 0 },
                { field: "Package_Type", headerText: "Type", type: "string", width: 100, foreignKeyField: "value", foreignKeyValue: "text", dataSource: pkgtypes },
                { field: "Package_Description", headerText: "Description", type: "string", width: 200 },
                { field: "Customer_ID", headerText: "Customer", type: "string", width: 220, foreignKeyField: "value", foreignKeyValue: "text", dataSource: customerList },
                { field: "Subdivision_ID", headerText: "Subdivision", type: "string", width: 220, foreignKeyField: "value", foreignKeyValue: "text", dataSource: subdivisionList },
                { field: "HoursWithChildren", headerText: "Hours (*)", type: "numeric", format: "{0:N0}", width: 100 },
                { field: "Floor", headerText: "Location", width: 150, template: true, templateID: "#floortmp" },
                { field: "Location", headerText: "Room", width: 150, template: true, templateID: "#locationtmp" },
                { field: "Qty", headerText: "Qty", width: 100, template: true, templateID: "#qtytmp" },
                {
                    headerText: "", textAlign: "center",
                    commands: [
                        { type: "Add", buttonOptions: { width: "80%", text: "+", click: "cloneRow" } }
                    ],
                    width: 130
                }
            ],

//this is my function attempts

function cloneRow() {
//JS attempt
        var tableDiv = document.getElementById('lstSelected');
        var tableClass = tableDiv.getElementsByClassName('e-table')[1];
        console.log(tableClass);

        tableDiv.appendChild(tableClass);
        resizeGrids();
}

//jQuery attempt
function cloneRow()  {
    var $tableBody = $('#Grid').find("tbody"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
        $trNew = $trLast.clone();
    $trLast.after($trNew);

    var $lastRow = $("[id$=blah] tr:not('.ui-widget-header'):last");
    //grab row before the last row
    var $newRow = $lastRow.clone();
    //clone it
    $newRow.find(":text").val("");
    //clear out textbox values    
    $lastRow.after($newRow);
    //add in the new row at the end
  }

}
```

I would like the row cloned, with full functionality of the row, not a stripped out version. I also have a demo/attempt here: http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/dexgxk03

Answer (score 0):

Query: **I would like the row cloned, with full functionality of the row, not a stripped out version**.

From the shared demo, we would see that you added the cloned row under the current row. Since cloned row is **not updated in the dataSource**, we are **unable to perform** the grid functions like s**orting, editing, filtering etc**., for the cloned row.

And also we need some additional detail regarding your requirement. So, please get back to us with the following details.

1. Please confirm whether you want to perform grid actions for the cloned row (i.e. sorting, filtering etc.,)
2. If not please explain your requirement in detail.
3. And also we would like to know the reason for cloning the grid row.

The requested details will help us to achieve your requirement as early as possible.

Comment: Yes, want to be able to perform grid actions on the row. We want the row cloned per a business requirement, basically user will be able to optionally add an additional row, and change the rows value. In the additional row (s), they do not need a clone functionality, just the first one.